# Regridding latitudes and longitudes with interpolation

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpolation, latitude-longitude

How would I go about regridding a weather map that uses two separate 2D arrays for latitudes and longitudes that makes a map as shown:

[image: weather_map]

Into a new, smaller grid consisting of two 1D arrays for latitude and longitudes?

(These are the new latitudes and longitudes for reference)

`new_lats = np.linspace(-34, -48, 14*4+1)`, `new_lons = np.linspace(166, 182, 16*4+1)`

I have looked into `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`, but couldn't get it to work and the processing time was simply long.

(Update: I have looked into xESMF, however, when using its Regridder function I get this error `ImportError: Regrid(filename) requires PIO and does not work if ESMF has not been built with MPI support`)

Comment: In numpy/scipy you can use [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html?highlight=griddata#scipy.interpolate.griddata) for irregular/unstructured data and [map_coordinates](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html?highlight=griddata#scipy.interpolate.griddata) for regular/structured data. From your post, it's hard to understand what your input looks like and what output should look like. Check out [interpolation tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I have just found a solution through the use of xESMF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further tinkering with xESMF and reading various forums, I discovered that xESMF has some dependency issues in the latest release, so `$ conda install -c conda-forge esmpy==7.1.0` managed to solve my problem, and then using the regridder function.